# How can I configure an "INDEPENDENT" .NET application with DB Connection to Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, odac

I have a WebService developed in .NET which connects to an Oracle Database. To do that I use the ODAC which Oracle Provides.

But every time I need to install my application on the Client Machines, I have so much trouble regarding the "Oracle Client", depending on if he already has an Oracle Client installed that is not the same version, or if he has one with a different platform (32bit, 64 bit), or anything else.

The point is I spend too much time trying to fix that thing every time.

Is there a way I can configure my application that I can install it, and it has everything it needs. And I don't need to worry about what the server has installed or what will be installed on it. Is there a way?

Comment: It would help if you posted the steps you are having to perform on each client machine *every time* you are installing your application.  That would help logically build a programmatic procedure, or help expose the issue more clearly.

Comment: @EvanL at each client is different. This time I needed to unistall all the ODAC he already had, and install the one I used for developing my app. But then the client re-install the one he previously had and the app failed again. I tried installing, the same they had in my developing machine, but I need a 32 bit version and they have the 64 bit version. So right now I'm just stucked.

Answer (score 1):

ODP.NET is distributable and multiple versions can be installed on one machine. You can include it with your app and that will minimize versioning issues.

It sounds like you are currently using the unmanaged ODP.NET driver. If so, have a look at the XCopy install. You can look at how the scripts work and include them in your own install.

If you can use the Fully Managed ODP.NET that will mostly eliminate the 32-bit vs 64-bit issue (unless you are using distributed transactions). And it is only 10 MB.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index-101716.html

Comment: If I use this "managed version" and set the library to copy local, I don't need to install anything but my app in the client? Will I have any trouble with others versions already installed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check out the Oracle Instant Client?

[Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html)

The Basic download contains all files needed if you're only wanting to connect to the db from your .Net app.  I have used this a lot in the past.  Simple install, too.

Comment: But haven't you to equally install it on each client before deploying your 'App'? I mean wouldn't you have the same versions problems as with the ODAC

Comment: @Laggel You are correct, I had to install the OIC on each PC when deploying the app.  It was a small install, though, but it worked exactly how I needed it to.

Comment: ODAC Xcopy installation includes the instant client. So rather than going this route (installing instant client on all machines first), just bundle the XCopy installation as part of your own install.